# Why I see this CLion error when iterating over yaml_cpp node?

Tags: yaml, c++17, clion

I have the following simple iteration over [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial) node that contains a list of items:

```
for (const auto &group_entry: node["groups"]) { /*...*/ }
```

The code compiles and works as expected, but in CLion IDE it is addressed as an error, claiming "const YAML::Node' is not a valid range type". Is it any problem with this and if not, how could I remove this annoying highlight? This is a C++17 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the compiler is the better judge of whether some code is valid or not. Your code is perfectly fine.

The error message also gives us a hint at what seems to be the problem: It talks about a *range type* which simply is not a thing in this context (C++20 `ranges` library does exist but is irrelevant here). The [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) you are using simply requires the *range-expression* to be either an array, have `begin` and `end` functions defined, or be a *braced-init-list*.

So what we are seeing is likely the result of CLion not correctly checking this restraint, possibly by re-using code from JetBrains' other IDEs that is not appropriate for C++. The [issue you created](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-26565) is therefore appropriate way of making this error go away.